# why initial mark and concurrent mark needs to scan young generation since final remark scan all the young generation

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

As cms working, final remark has to scan all the young generation, so what's the benefit of "initial mark and concurrent mark scanning the young generation". Why not save the time, leave it to the remark phase.

As we know the concurrent-abortable-preclean is not always processed.

Comment: as an addendum - CMS is done, don't lose too much time with it. No support provided and removed since jdk-14.

Answer (score 0):

In CMS, initial mark and final remark call **STW(Stop the world)** pause. This means application stop and GC continue the operation. The time elapsed at these stages is referred to as the **pause time**.

In the initial mark phase, GC will scan root and mark live objects. In Concurrent mark phase, GC is marking live objects concurrently with application threads running, it must record any changes to objects that are already traced. In Final remark, GC will find and mark objects which missed by concurrent phase.

If you want to do it all in one step, you will see huge pause-times(latency) and it will be not efficient. In a nutshell reduced pause-times with these steps.

References:

[Concurrent mark](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/mm_gc_mark_concurrent.html)

[CMS Oracle Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html)